# Can't get quotes right

Tags: php, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

and a you saw on the title. I can't get the quotes right with php. I want to export some variables to another file, but i can't get it quoted right, anybody that can help me?

This is my code:

```
    if($sliderconfig = fopen("./slidersettings.class.php", "w")) {
        $error[] = 'Er was een probleem met het veranderen van de slider_config, contacteer site-admin.';
    }
    $configuration = '<?php
    $slider_text = '.$slider_text.';
    $text_link = '.$text_link.';
    $slider_speed = '.$slider_speed.';
    $text_size = '.$text_size.';
    ?>';
    fwrite($sliderconfig, $configuration);
    fclose($sliderconfig);
    $message[] = 'De configuratie is succesvol bijgwerkt!';
```

This is the ouput:

```
<?php
    $slider_text = test;
    $text_link = test;
    $slider_speed = test;
    $text_size = test;
    ?>
```

And this should be the ouput:

```
<?php
    $slider_text = 'test';
    $text_link = 'test';
    $slider_speed = 'test';
    $text_size = 'test';
    ?>
```

Anyone that nows how to fix this, if so and you answer it down here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it's better to store the keys and values in an array and then append to your file in a loop.. imo you code will look much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the single quotes in the string by using a backslash `\` before the single quote like so:

```
$configuration = '<?php
    $slider_text = \''.$slider_text.'\';
    $text_link = \''.$text_link.'\';
    $slider_speed = \''.$slider_speed.'\';
    $text_size = \''.$text_size.'\';
    ?>';
```

---

Alternatively you can use double quotes in the string and single quotes to encase the string:

```
$configuration = '<?php
    $slider_text = "'.$slider_text.'";
    $text_link = "'.$text_link.'";
    $slider_speed = "'.$slider_speed.'";
    $text_size = "'.$text_size.'";
    ?>';
```

Comment: As of i can't accept your answer within 10m i will do that soon

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$configuration = '
    $slider_text = "'.$slider_text.'";
    $text_link = "'.$text_link.'";
    $slider_speed = "'.$slider_speed.'";
    $text_size = "'.$text_size.'";
    ';
echo $configuration;
```

Output:

```
$slider_text = "aaa"; 
$text_link = "aaa"; 
$slider_speed = "aaa"; 
$text_size = "aaa";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is yours:

```
    if($sliderconfig = fopen("./slidersettings.class.php", "w")) {
    $error[] = 'Er was een probleem met het veranderen van de slider_config, contacteer site-admin.';
}
$configuration = '<?php
$slider_text = '.$slider_text.';
$text_link = '.$text_link.';
$slider_speed = '.$slider_speed.';
$text_size = '.$text_size.';
?>';
fwrite($sliderconfig, $configuration);
fclose($sliderconfig);
$message[] = 'De configuratie is succesvol bijgwerkt!';
```

And this is how it should be:

```
if($sliderconfig = fopen("./slidersettings.class.php", "w")) {
    $error[] = 'Er was een probleem met het veranderen van de slider_config, contacteer site-admin.';
}
$configuration = '<?php
$slider_text = "'.$slider_text.'";
$text_link = "'.$text_link.'";
$slider_speed = "'.$slider_speed.'";
$text_size = "'.$text_size.'";
?>';
fwrite($sliderconfig, $configuration);
fclose($sliderconfig);
$message[] = 'De configuratie is succesvol bijgwerkt!';
```

Comment: Actually this wouldn't work, as double quotes concatenates any PHP variable inside - e.g. `$a="test"; echo "$a";` would output *test*. As `$slider_text` is a variable (*test*), the output would be *test = test*.